# Realloc a Struct which contains a pointer to another Sruct (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c, pointers, struct, realloc

I have two Structs like this:

```
typedef struct Student {
    char name[80];
    char sclass[4];
    int phone;
} Student;

typedef struct Cell {
    Student* p_student; // pointer to struct
    bool occupied; // if the cell has been occupied for collisions after delete
} Cell;
```

And two arrays that are initially allocated with malloc :

```
Cell *arr_name = malloc(sizeof(Cell) * size),
     *arr_phone = malloc(sizeof(Cell) * size);
```

The problem is, when I try to use Realloc I get the segmentation fault error :

```
void insert(int *size, int *numberOfStudents, Cell **arr_name, Cell **arr_phone, char name[80], char sclass[4], int phone) {
// some stuff happening

if(*numberOfStudents > (*size / 1.5)) {
    *size = *numberOfStudents * 1.5;
    int new_size = sizeof(Cell) * (*size);
    Cell *p_name = realloc(*arr_name, new_size); // <-- ERROR HERE
    Cell *p_phone = realloc(*arr_phone, new_size);
    if(p_name && p_phone) {
        *arr_name = p_name;
        *arr_phone = p_phone;
    }
    else printf("Couldn't allocate more memory");
}
```

Thanks for help !

Comment: @StoryTeller ahh, I missed that part. _naming things....._.. :)

Comment: Paul, please create a [mcve] to demonstrate the issue. Questions must contain just enough code to reproduce the problem, but not too much so we wouldn't be able to just copy-paste it and check for ourselves.

Comment: @StoryTeller I tried but couldn't reproduce the error in a test environment, I could send you the whole project in private message if you're interested though. Thank you for answering by the way :)

Comment: If you couldn't reproduce the problem, it means you need to debug your program further. Try running it through valgrind for starters.

Comment: The problem doesn't appear when I run the program with valgrind, this is very weird... It doesn't show any error before the end of the program

Comment: Forget my previous message, I was using the wrong command. I have tons of "Invalid write at size ..." errors. I guess it comes from there.

Comment: Yup. that would corrupt your heap plenty.

Comment: Problem solved ! Thank you guys ! I had some lines like "if XXX == NULL" and that was apparently messing up with the memory. How do I state the problem as solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved !

Thanks to @StoryTeller that suggested to use valgrind to debug memory errors. The memory was messed up by some other stuff in the program.